# "Topologification" of a subcollection of a power set

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, category-theory

Let $X$ be any set and consider any $\mathscr{S} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$, where the latter is the power set. It is natural to ask if we make $X$ a topological space by the subcollection $\mathscr{S}$. One possible way is to consider the coarsest topology on $X$ that contains $\mathscr{S}$. It is unique if it exists, and I think it does exist by taking the intersection of all topologies that contain $\mathscr{S}$ (such as $\mathscr{P}(X)$). This way, we can get the "best topological approximation" of $\mathscr{S}$, so I was wondering if this is a notion of "topologifying" $\mathscr{S}$ just like we groupify natural numbers to get integers or sheafify a presheaf to get a sheaf. Thus I want to think of this notion functorialy, and I am pretty sure this is left-adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of topologies on $X$ to the category of subsets of $X$ (corrected from "the category of topological space to the category of sets" thanks to Zhen Lin).

However, since I am not a professional mathematician, I am not sure if this is a correct thinking; hence the question. A short answer or any reference would suffice though I am not going to accept any answer till I get through this thought. Thanks in advance.

---

Edited (2/23): I was confused on which categories I was working in. As Zhen Lin said, the forgetful functor is from the powerset to the category of topologies on $X$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed a left adjoint, but not between the categories you mention. Instead, let us regard $\mathscr{P} (\mathscr{P} (X))$ as a category where the objects are the subsets of $\mathscr{P} (X)$ and the morphisms are the inclusions. There is a full subcategory $\mathscr{T} (X)$ consisting of topologies on $X$, and it is not hard to see that $\mathscr{T} (X)$ is closed under arbitrary intersections. Thus, the inclusion $\mathscr{T} (X) \hookrightarrow \mathscr{P} (\mathscr{P} (X))$ has a left adjoint, constructed as you say.

Comment: Right. Sorry I was confused!

Comment: I corrected above, mentioning what I wrote previously. I know this discussion is a trivial remark, but I would be happy if I have a reference for it. Thanks for the answer.